# Getting Daily Async Apex Execution limits onto Visualforce page to monitor

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, governorlimits

We recently breached our aync apex execution limits on some objects that were loaded on any kind of case interaction, like case creation and modification

I know that you can find the limits via Workbench through the REST explorer, but i'd like to be able to get these onto a VF page, in particular the DailyAsyncApexExecutions and DailyApiRequests limits with their maximums and remaining values:

[image]

**So I want to get these values:**

[image]

**And display them on a VF page**

I believe that the VF should be written *something* like this, but I want to be able to specify the limits it pulls:

```
<apex:page>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Get Accounts via the REST API
  $.ajax('/services/data/v40.0/limits',
    {
      success: function(response) {
        $.each(response.records, function(index, record) {
          $('#list').append('<li>'+record.id+'</li>');
        });
      }
      }
    }
  );
 });
</script>
<h1>Limit usage</h1>
<div>list:</div>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: might help you [Org Limits](https://github.com/jthurst01/OrgLimits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make same request from apex to get the data

```
public static HttpResponse getLimitsResp() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        Http http = new Http();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        String url = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm() +'/services/data/v40.0/limits';
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        return http.send(req);
    }
```

There is a Open Source Git available which you can refer [Org Limits](https://github.com/jthurst01/OrgLimits)

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I copied the code and amended sections of it from the Git link that @Tushar posted

I now have this as a VF page (I have amended it to remove some of the gauges):

[image]